# Weird behaviour of a local pointer

Tags: c, sorting, pointers, divide-and-conquer

**This code finds the smallest and largest element in an array using divide and conquer**:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX(a, b) ((a>=b)?a:b)
#define MIN(a, b) ((a<=b)?a:b)

void printarr(int *arr, int base, int height){
    int i;
    for (i = base; i <=height; i++){
        printf("arr[%d] = %d \n", i, arr[i]);
    }
}

//This function divides the array into partition recursively until a partition of 1 / 2 element(s) is reached
//and then compares the elements 
int* partition(int *arr, int base, int height){
    printf("\n\n");
    printarr(arr, base, height);
    int mid = (base + height)/2;
    //The local array holds the largest and smallest elements 
    //of the partition in max_min[0] and max_min[1] respectively
    int max_min[2];
    //The next two integer pointers will point to the base 
    //address of the array returned(max_min[2]) by next recursive call
    //Please continue reading to get it 
    int *max_min_temp;
    int *max_min_temp_1;

    //The if block is executed when the partition holds exactly one
    //element the largest and the smallest elements are the same
    if(base == height){
        max_min[0] = arr[base];
        max_min[1] = arr[height];
        //The max_min[0] and max_min[1] holds the same element
        printf("%d %d\n", max_min[0], max_min[1]);
        //The base address of the array is now returned
        return max_min;
    }
    //This else if block is executed when the there's exactly two elements
    //In the partition and a simple comparison is done to find the minimum 
    //and maximum elements of the partition and store in max_min[1] and max_min[0]
    //respectively 
    else if((height - base) == 1){
        max_min[0] = MAX(arr[base], arr[height]);
        max_min[1] = MIN(arr[base], arr[height]);
        printf("%d %d\n", max_min[0], max_min[1]);
        //The base address of the array is now returned
        return max_min;
    }

    //This block is executed when more than two elements are there in the partition 
    else{
        //Now the local partition is divided into two partition from the middle

        //The max_min of the first half of the partition is pointed by max_min_temp
        max_min_temp = partition(arr, base, mid);

        //The max_min of the second half of the partition is pointed by max_min_temp_1
        max_min_temp_1 = partition(arr, mid+1, height);

        //----------------------THE PROBLEM ARISES HERE----------------------------//
        //The max_min_temp and max_min_temp_1 act as if they point to the same array    

        // and hence compares the same elements 
        max_min[0] = MAX(max_min_temp[0], max_min_temp_1[0]);
        max_min[1] = MIN(max_min_temp[1], max_min_temp_1[1]);
        //It can be seen here in the following printf statement
        printf("\nCHECKPOINT #1 - %d %d %d %d\n",max_min_temp[0], max_min_temp[1],max_min_temp_1[0], max_min_temp_1[1]);

        //Check the corresponding output of the printf statement
        printf("\nCHECKPOINT #2 - %d %d\n", max_min[0], max_min[1]);
        return max_min;

    }

}
/*int main(int argc, int *argv[]){
    int i;
    int arr[argc-1];
    int *max_min;
    for(i=1; i<argc; i++)
        sscanf(argv[i],"%d",&arr[i-1]);
    max_min = partition(arr, 0, argc-2);
    printf("\nMax = %d Min = %d\n", max_min[0], max_min[1]);
    return 0;
}*/
int main(){
    int arr[] = {20, 30, 5, 10};
    int *max_min = partition(arr, 0, 3);
    printf("\nMax = %d Min = %d\n", max_min[0], max_min[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

The Output is :

```
arr[0] = 20 
arr[1] = 30 
arr[2] = 5 
arr[3] = 10 


arr[0] = 20 
arr[1] = 30 
30 20


arr[2] = 5 
arr[3] = 10 
10 5

CHECKPOINT #1 - 10 5 10 5

CHECKPOINT #2 - 10 5

Max = 10 Min = 5
```

Which is not correct.

Now if I replace the **else** block with the following else block, It works fine.

```
else{

    max_min_temp = partition(arr, mid+1, height);
    max_min[0] = max_min_temp[0];
    max_min[1] = max_min_temp[1];
    max_min_temp_1 = partition(arr, base, mid);
    max_min[0] = MAX(max_min[0],max_min_temp_1[0]);
    max_min[1] = MIN(max_min[1],max_min_temp_1[1]);


    //printf("%d %d\n", max_min[0], max_min[1]);
    return max_min;

}
```

Now the Output is:

```
arr[0] = 20 
arr[1] = 30 
arr[2] = 5 
arr[3] = 10 


arr[2] = 5 
arr[3] = 10 
10 5


arr[0] = 20 
arr[1] = 30 
30 20

Max = 30 Min = 5
```

which is the desired one.

Seem that both the local pointer is holding the same array... But how? Please help. Thank you

Comment: Did you use the debugger? Where **exactly** does it go wrong? Which pointer behaves unexpected?

Comment: Please debug the program. You have all the required tools.

Comment: Please help now. I have added the output.

Comment: I don't know why people are downvoting the question. I mean many people answered the question -so they understood and I very well got where the problem was. I am new to this forum and maybe people are getting me wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array `max_min` is returning a local address which is resulting same every time. The possible solution is to do Dynamic memory allocation.

```
int *max_min;
max_min = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
```

Replace the line `int* max_min[2]` with above 2 lines.

Comment: Yes thank you so much, But can you please explain your answer .. like how does the return statement differs when returning an array which is dynamically allocated and the one which is statically allocated.

Comment: Dynamic allocation allocate memory on Heap whereas on the contrary local variables are allocated in stack. Every stack has life only until that particular function call. Hence, one the value is returned, your address becomes invalid. If it is on a heap then that can be access when the control returns from your function.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing back a *pointer* to the array `max_min`, which is allocated on the *previous* stack frame.

Now in the first implementation you call `partition` twice consecutively. The second call will *overwrite* the values of your *first* `max_min` array (i.e. the one your `max_min_temp` is *supposed* to point to). So the `max_min` values you get are always fro the second call.

In the second implementation you copy the values of `max_min` to variables on your *current* stack frame, *before* you call `partition` again. THAT is why your values are correct.

Bottom line is, either pass pointers of `max` and `min` on your current stack frame to `partition`, or use `malloc` as Ajit said.

```
void partition(int* arr, int base, int height, int* max, int* min)
{
    // your code...

    int max_1, max_2, min_1, min_2;
    partition(arr, base, mid, &max_1, &min_1); 
    partition(arr, mid+1, height, &max_2, &min_2);
    *max = MAX(max_1 , max_2);
    *min = MIN(min_1 , min_2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in other answers, what you are doing is to overwrite the previously allocated stack, and you have got the solution as well, to allocate dynamic memory. I would just like to add one thing, **Don't Forget** to `free()` the allocated memory, otherwise your code will have *memory leak*. In case of functions returning pointers to dynamically allocated memory, it is the responsibility of caller to `free()`the memory. So in `main()`, before returning `free()`the memory.

```
int *max_min = partition(arr, 0, 3);
printf("\nMax = %d Min = %d\n", max_min[0], max_min[1]);
free(max_min); //frees the memory allocated in partition().
max_min = NULL; //Make it point to null, so that it is not pointing to any random location.
return 0;
```